# Android performance: place resources in common library or in each project

Tags: android, performance

I'm creating an android project which will have 2 versions, and i'm planning to use a library to place all the common code for both versions.

I could not find any info related to the performance of the resources: Is it better to place all the images, logos etc in the common library, or place them in each of the projects?

Answer (score 2):

To reduce duplication, you'd put them into common library. But there's certainly a better way if you're using gradle(which Android Studio supports), which is **[Build Variant](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants)**.

With this method, you can build multiple various versions of a single app.